# How we give alert/log when can't connect to the server or server is down in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, try-catch

I am confused how to alert/log the user when the server is down/offline.

I have a table load with GET method.

**UserList.jsx**

```
const getUsers = async () => {
  try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/users');
      setUsers(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

How do we alert the user if the server is down/offline (in this case I shutdown my local server), as a alert or something.
While we can't give status code response from backend server because it doesn't running.

Thank your for reading.